# Generate secure URL external in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the function `esc_url_raw`..

```
WordPress function:
esc_url_raw( string $url, array $protocols = null )
```

How do I print a url with "https"?

```
Example:
input: http://example.com
ouput: https://example.com
```

[Doc Function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url_raw/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the acceptable protocols in the `$protocols` variable. It can be a `array()` of protocols like `http`, `https`. You can refer [wp_allowed_protocols](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_allowed_protocols/) for allowed protocols.

For your answer you can provide an array for `$protocols` as `array('http', 'https')` as the argument to `esc_url_raw`.

If you are actually looking to convert a URL from `http` to `https` then you can define something like:

```
function convert_to_https(url){
    $new_url = preg_replace("/^http:/i", "https:", $url);
    return $new_url;
}


$https_url = convert_to_https('http://example.com');
echo $https_url; // https://example.com

// then escape the URL
esc_url_raw($https_url);
```

Comment: Thanks, the function **esc_url_raw** what allows me is to validate the url and escape the characters that do not belong to the url.